# How do I set a Generic type as a Reflect type variable?

Tags: scala, generics, reflection

I have a class that accepts Generic types, but I want to pass in the generic type to the class at runtime, using a Reflect.Type variable. The class is documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html

I wrote a function that accepts a list of Generic type class names as Strings, and maps them to the corresponding Generic Type using reflection

```
def getGenericTypeByName(names: Map[String, String]): Map[String, reflect.Type] = {

  val declaredFields = Types.getClass.getDeclaredFields.toSeq;

  val types: Map[String, reflect.Type] = names.map(s => {
    val fieldType = declaredFields.find(_.getName.equals(s._2)).getOrElse(null);
    if (fieldType != null) {
      (s._1, fieldType.getGenericType);
    } else {
      (s._1, null);
    }
  });
}
```

The return value is a Map of Reflect.Type, which should be passable to a Generic type parameter in a class, so I should be able to do this:

```
types.map(s => this.GenericClassMap.get(s._1).get.read[s._2]());
```

But when I compile, I get the error `Cannot resolve symbol _2`

What is missing here? _2 should be accesible since it's a map, and it's of a reflect type which I think should match the generic type too.

Comment: You are trying to use a computed value in the place that a type is required. A type value is not the same as a type. Hence, `s._2` cannot be found.

Comment: You won't be able to invoke the `read[T]()` method that way, with knowledge of what `T` is. If `T` is known at compile time, you can `match` against the value and invoke `read[T]()` in the matching clause.

Comment: The answer to this depends on what you're trying to do with the (erased) type. Can you provide the `read` method you're calling as well? The short answer is you need to add an implicit `ClassTag` or `TypeTag` parameter to the method.